# Text before price in opencart (I apologize if this is duplicated)

Tags: php, opencart2.3

I would like to know how do I add text before price in opencart?

I have tried to modify the following code in catalog/view/theme/customtheme/template/product/product.tpl

Default

```
<li class="product-price"><?php echo $price; ?></li>
<li class="price-old"><?php echo $price; ?></li>
```

After Modified

```
<li class="product-price"><div class="custom-price">Price:</div><?php echo $price; ?></li>
<li class="price-old"><div class="custom-price">Price:</div><?php echo $price; ?></li>
```

It works correctly, but when I chose the option selection such as size or colour, the "Price:" text will disappear.

[My domain](http://www.ry-express.com)

I apologize if this is a duplicated question.

Answer (score 0):

This product is listed as $1.00, I assume that's a mistake: http://ry-express.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=280

What do you mean it "disappears," like it literally is no longer visible?

Do you have `visibility:hidden` or `display:none` in your stylesheet for any formation of the `custom-price` class?

Default behavior of Opencart, that would not be occuring if you edit the template directly with text.  There's either a stylesheet entry or perhaps Ajax/javascript on that field, also; that triggers the loss.

Do you have a link to a product directly where this happens?